# Margin of caption of table

Tags: tables, captions, margins

I have a table which is wider than my usual margins. This results in the table violating the right margin. (putting table in landscape wont work because of the length)
I want to have a caption of the same size as the table. I can adjust the left, but not the right margin. Is there a way to make it violate the right margin as well ? Or alternatively, a way to have my table violate the left margin instead of the right.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, array, float, subfig}
 \usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
 \usepackage{graphicx, natbib, cite}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{caption} 
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{width=1.5\textwidth, margin=0em}
\setlength{\leftskip}{\captionmargin}%
\caption{Title\\ \small Columns 1 and 2 show the effect of blablablalab}
    \begin{tabular}[]{p{2,15cm}p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm}} \hline

                     & (1)      & (2)                & (3)      & (4)      & (5)      & (6)      & (7)                & (8)                \\
     Dep.Var.Name                & Dep.Var.Name & \(\Delta\)Dep.Var.Name & Dep.Var.Name & Dep.Var.Name & Dep.Var.Name & Dep.Var.Name & \(\Delta\)Dep.Var.Name & \(\Delta\)Dep.Var.Name \\ \hline
                     &          &                    &          &          & \\          
     LONG NAME FE            & Yes      & No                 & Yes      & Yes      & Yes      & Yes      & No                 & No                 \\ \hline
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
     \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Not related to your problem, but I believe you are missing a ``\\`` before `LONG NAME FE`

Comment: your right, corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to put it is that `\caption` likes to be inside a `minipage`.  BTW, I modified "Dep.Var.Name." to fit the `p{}` field.

I take it all those packages are there to test compatibility?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, array, float, subfig}
 \usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
 \usepackage{graphicx, natbib, cite}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{caption} 
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{afterpage}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\hspace*{\dimexpr -\oddsidemargin-1in}\rlap{\begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}
\caption{Title\\ \small Columns 1 and 2 show the effect of blablablalab}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}[]{p{2,15cm}p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm} p{1.45cm}} \hline
                     & (1)      & (2)                & (3)      & (4)      & (5)      & (6)      & (7)                & (8)                \\
     Dep. Var. Name                & Dep. Var. Name & $(\Delta)$Dep. Var. Name & Dep. Var. Name & Dep. Var. Name & Dep. Var. Name & Dep. Var. Name & $(\Delta)$Dep. Var. Name & $(\Delta)$Dep. Var. Name \\ \hline
                     &          &                    &          &          & \\          
     LONG NAME FE            & Yes      & No                 & Yes      & Yes      & Yes      & Yes      & No                 & No                 \\ \hline
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
     \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image: full width of page]

Answer (score 2):

Just changing the horizontal margin to 2.5cm, it can fit text width using `tabularx` and `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=3cm, showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, array, float, subfig}
 \usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
 \usepackage{graphicx, natbib, cite}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
 \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} \usepackage{afterpage}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}[flushleft]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\caption{Title\\ \small Columns 1 and 2 show the effect of blablablalab}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=1.8\hsize\raggedright}X *{8}{>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X}}%
     \toprule
    & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) \\
    Dep.Var.Name & Dep.Var.\newline Name & $ \Delta $Dep.\newline Var.Name & Dep.Var.\newline Name & Dep.Var.\newline Name & Dep.Var.\newline Name & Dep.Var.\newline Name & \(\Delta\)Dep.\newline Var.Name & \(\Delta\)Dep.\newline Var.Name \\
    \midrule
 LONG NAME FE & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & No & No \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
     \end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
  \item[]Robust standard errors in parentheses
\item[]*** p${}<0.01$, ** p$ {}<0.05$, * p${}<0.1$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a solution to your problem, but a suggestion on how you could improve the look of it, and make it fit into the text. I realise this may not be something that you can use, but I don't think you should violate the margins.

- Remove the repeating header title `Variable`, as it is already in the leftmost header. I don't see a reason for repeating it in every row.
- Instead of specifying the width of every row, just use `c` or `l` here. Also, for many rows of the same type, the syntax `*{num}{type}` makes it a lot clearer.
- Use `\cemtering` inside the `table` environment. Of course, if you really want the table to span outside margins, there is no point in this suggestion.
- Are you really using all these different and very related packages? Consider sticking to a certain style. Be consistent everywhere. Remove unused packages.
- Consider using `booktabs`-style. You are already creating better-looking tables than most, as you are not using vertical lines. Many think that some horizontal lines of different weight improve the look and readability. `booktabs` can help in keeping consistent line weights for all tables, by using `\toprule`,`\midrule` and `\bottomrule`.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, float, subfig}
%\usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{graphicx, natbib, cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption} 
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Local leverage\\ \small Columns 1 and 2 show the effect of blablablalab}
    \begin{tabular}{l *{8}{c}} 
    \toprule

     Variables      & (1)       & (2)\(\Delta\) & (3)       & (4)       & (5)      & (6)      & (7)\(\Delta\)       & (8)\(\Delta\)      \\   
     Long Name Fe   & Yes       & No            & Yes       & Yes       & Yes      & Yes      & No                  & No                 \\ 
     \bottomrule
     \addlinespace
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
     \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, still learning LaTeX. Everytime I run into a problem someone suggests some new package. Thanks for the suggestions.